# Count rows which has the same ID and display on the table

Tags: database, ms-access, count, ms-access-2016

This is the original table:

```
| ID | Card_No |
|----+---------|
| 1  | 6453671 |
| 1  | 8795732 |
| 1  | 9948495 |
| 2  | 7483009 |
| 2  | 1029001 |
| 3  | 7463094 |
```

Is it possible to make it like this? Which will be adding a calculated column the the original table?

```
| ID | Card_No | Total |
|----+---------|-------|
| 1  | 6453671 |   3   |
| 1  | 8795732 |   3   |
| 1  | 9948495 |   3   |
| 2  | 7483009 |   2   |
| 2  | 1029001 |   2   |
| 3  | 7463094 |   3   |
```

I'm using **Microsoft Access**, and I've tried code like this:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT (*) AS Total FROM Table GROUP BY ID
```

But I did not get the result I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, saving the calculated value back into table is not only unnecessary but bad design.

Options:

1. build a report that counts records with an expression in textbox
2. build aggregate query then another query joining aggregate query to the table
3. DCount() domain aggregate function in query